# Update Database Data in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-4

Please bear with my noobness, I'm super new to Asp.NET MVC, I don't really understand it yet.

Basically what I want to do is to update a table in my database from information entered into a form. 
I have a registration form with several options: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`, `Sex`, `SecretQuestion`, `SecretQuestionAnswer`.

I'd like to insert this data in my UserProfile table (I use SimpleMembershipProvider) to the corresponding columns.
Here's my complete Register ActionResult in my main controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [RecaptchaControlMvc.CaptchaValidatorAttribute]
        public ActionResult Regisztracio(RegisterModel model, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!captchaValid)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("recaptcha", captchaErrorMessage);
                    return View(model);
                }

                try
                {
                    OneMillionDb db = new OneMillionDb();
                    User user = new User();

                    var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, true);
                    user.LastName = model.LastName;
                    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    user.Age = model.Age;
                    user.Sex = model.Sex;
                    user.SecretQuestion = model.SecretQuestion;
                    user.SecretQuestionAnswer = model.SecretQuestionAnswer;
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();



                        return RedirectToAction("Index");


                }
                catch
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "The username already exists.");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "The specified E-mail address already exists.");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmEmail", "");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

`OneMillionDb` is my dbContext model file:

```
public class OneMillionDb : DbContext
    {
        public OneMillionDb()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

`User` is my model class for table definiton. It looks like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [Required]
        public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }
        [Column]
        [Required]
        public string SecretQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int MoneyIn { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int MoneyOut { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int TimesWon { get; set; }
    }
```

I used to work in ASP.NET Web Pages, in that I'd use the `UPDATE` SQL statement to do this then execute the query..

Edit3: Here's my Register view:

```
@model OneMillion.Models.RegisterModel
@using Recaptcha;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Register</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Age)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Age)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Sex)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Sex)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecretQuestion)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SecretQuestion)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecretQuestionAnswer)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SecretQuestionAnswer)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here's my RegisterModel:

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Felhasználónév")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail cím")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "E-mail cím megerősítése")]
        [Compare("Email", ErrorMessage = "A két e-mail cím nem egyezik.")]
        public string ConfirmEmail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A jelszónak legalább {2} karakter hosszúnak kell lennie.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Jelszó")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Jelszó megerősítése")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A jelszó és a jelszó megerősítése mezők nem egyeznek.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Display(Name= "Vezetéknév")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name= "Keresztnév")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name= "Életkor")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Nem")]
        public string Sex { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Titkos kérdés")]
        public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Titkos kérdés válasza")]
        public string SecretQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit:
**My Problem:**

The database doesn't get updated. I know this since I get an Exception stating that Column Age can't have a value of `NULL`, but the corresponding input was filled out.

Edit2:
I also changed the code to reflect **SOfanatic**'s answer, but I still get the error.

Edit4: Here's the exception I get in the Catch side of trycatch:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Age', table 'OneMillionDb.dbo.UserProfile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: As @Suhas alludes to, you haven't actually stated what the problem is. Does the code shown not work as you expect it to?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that part. I edited the question with details regarding the problem.

Comment: Does model.Age have any value when you debug? Can you profile the db and find get the actual insert statement is? Maybe the Age property is not getting mapped to the Table column. You could try putting the column Name in the Column attribute. [Column(Name="TableColumnName")]

Comment: @Satish Yes, it does have the value I entered in the form. I can't use [Column(Name="TableColumnName")] though, it gets underlined in red in VS. The error message:  'Name' is not a valid named attribute argument. Named attribute arguments must be fields which are not readonly, static, or const, or read-write properties which are public and not static. 
Also, I noticed that the exception gets thrown when the debugger starts the WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method.. I tried to put that to the bottom of the update and now I get this excpt: Validation failed for one or more entities.

Comment: sorry the attribute should be [Column("TableColumnName")]

Comment: The full last exception (didn't have enough room): Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. Edit: I changed all the [Colmn] attributes like you said, but I still get the error. Now I only get this exception. I put the websecurity.createuserandaccount under db.SaveChanges()

Comment: You have defined UserName as Required but I don't see you setting a value for UserName, that could be your Validation error.

Comment: You are right, this was the problem. I don't really understand tho why it threw that exception in the first place, the one in the question, and why it isn't thrown after moving the WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount method to the bottom.. Anyway, it works perfectely! Submit it as an answer please, so I can mark it as Correct Answer :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined UserName as required field in User class but you are not assigning any value to the field when saving. That is probably throwing the EntityValidationError.

Comment: The error mentioned in the question was on `Age` field though and not on `UserName` field.

Answer (score 1):

Updating an entity is similar to adding an entity, so in your code:

```
try {
   OneMillionDb db = new OneMillionDb();
   User user = new User();

   var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, true);
   user.LastName = model.LastName;
   user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
   user.Age = model.Age;
   user.Sex = model.Sex;
   user.SecretQuestion = model.SecretQuestion;
   user.SecretQuestionAnswer = model.SecretQuestionAnswer;
   db.Users.Add(user);
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

change the `db.Users.Add(user)` to `db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified`

Comment: I still get the error (I edited the question), thanks tho for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

On your `User` class change the following to

```
[Column]
[Required]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

to

```
[Column]
public int? Age { get; set; }
```

Your declaration is making the column `NOT NULL` and always mandatory.